# How to apply custom css style on markers not apply image or icon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to display marker content and custom style for the marker label.
After googling it. All the examples are talking about how to setIcon and providing image url which is not I want.

Is there a way to custom the label style like below?

Thanks

```
    <Marker
        key={loc.estimate_address}
        position={{
            lat: loc.lat,
            lng: loc.lng
        }}

        // I can only put STRING here! I thought we could put html snippet <label> XXXX </label>
        label={this.getMarkerLabel(loc)}


        onClick={e => this.onMarkerClick(null, loc, e)}
    >
```

## Expected

[image]

## Current version

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve the expected output using an SVG and writing text on it, taking advantage of the [setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons) method, like this:

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.4375, 12.3358),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });

    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setIcon(getIcon('Test'));
}

function getIcon(message) {
    var svg = '<svg width="140" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="5" d="m8,11.26568l123.54244,-3.20295l0.45756,54.45019l-41.63838,1.83026l-54.45019,38.89299l23.33579,-41.18081l-49.87454,3.20295l-1.37269,-53.99262z" id="svg_2"/><text fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" x="152.85671" y="81.24476" id="svg_3" font-size="24" font-family="serif" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(1.4942564059587096,0,0,1.018637442728764,-156.2965919229571,-38.08934344654804) " stroke="#000000">' + message + '</text></g></svg>'; 

    return {
            url: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svg),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(20,40)
        };
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xmo3dpn/1/)